# Check form data params against condition in controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a simple action in my controller triggered by a `before_filter` which checks to see if the user has selected a certain region in the corresponding active record/ model form submission. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and instead ignores the part of the `if` statement where I'm trying to see if the value is "not equal" to a certain region which is the `params[:country_id]` and `params[:state_id]` respectively. The only part which actually works is the check for the correct plan `@plan == 'plus'`.

Controller:

```
before_filter :check_region, :only => :create

def check_region
    @plan = params[:plan]
    if @plan == 'plus' && params[:country_id] != '1039' && params[:state_id] != ['52', '53', '60']
      redirect_to page_path('plans')
      flash[:notice] = "Unfortunatley the plan isn't available at this time in the region you selected."
    else

    end
  end
```

I'll also include the excerpt from the rails log when a form submission occurs on the `plus` plan type.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-06 01:16:50 -0800
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eYfsGY7vnItcRRyLEnFA9wJlkdZA5DxjPF/eQdwNm9M=", "plan"=>"plus", "user"=>{"fullname"=>"Example User", "email"=>"exampleuser@emailaddress.net", "country_id"=>"1039", "state_id"=>"52", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/plans
Filter chain halted as :check_region rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So in this case since the value of `country_id` and `state_id` were "1039" and "52" respectively, it should have not triggered the redirect which cancelled the form submission (and would have proceeded with the create method instead).

Comment: Params[:state_id] isn't an array, is is? Ypu should check if It is included in array, not if It is an array.

Comment: @zrl3dx :state_id is just a table in the DB with a list of states and their corresponding ID's, and on the form itself it's a form select menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the above code your accessing params[:country_id] and params[:state_id] but if you check the params passed it is within the user scope so it should be params[:user][:state_id] and params[:user][:country_id].

Comment: I thought it may have something to do with the user scope. Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The params are not accessed correctly also you need to check the value is in the array

```
if @plan == 'plus' && params[:user][:country_id] != '1039' && params[:user][:state_id].in?['52', '53', '60']
```